# How do I fix my JavaScript array when it comes back as undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm new to JavaScript and can't figure out why my array is coming back as undefined.

Here's my CodePen example: https://codepen.io/TiffSmith126/pen/dyJedWQ

I'm doing an outcome personality quiz that stores the answers in an array, I'm using a function to get the most frequently selected options in the array. However, instead of receiving the result I receive undefined. At this point my function doesn't work because my array is coming back as undefined. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// QUESTIONS

const questions = [
  {
    question: "Question 1",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 2",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 3",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 4",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 5",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 6",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 7",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 8",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 9",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 10",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  }
];

let currentQuestion = 0;
let score = [];
let selectedAnswersData = [];
let scoringData = [];
const totalQuestions = questions.length;

const container = document.querySelector(".quiz-container");
const questionEl = document.querySelector(".question");
const option1 = document.querySelector(".option1");
const option2 = document.querySelector(".option2");
const option3 = document.querySelector(".option3");
const nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");
const previousButton = document.querySelector(".previous");
const restartButton = document.querySelector(".restart");
const result = document.querySelector(".result");

//Function to generate question
function generateQuestions(index) {
  //Select each question by passing it a particular index
  const question = questions[index];
  const option1Total = questions[index].answer1Total;
  const option2Total = questions[index].answer2Total;
  const option3Total = questions[index].answer3Total;
  //Populate html elements
  questionEl.innerHTML = `${index + 1}. ${question.question}`;
  option1.setAttribute("data-total", `${option1Total}`);
  option2.setAttribute("data-total", `${option2Total}`);
  option3.setAttribute("data-total", `${option3Total}`);
  option1.innerHTML = `${question.answer1}`;
  option2.innerHTML = `${question.answer2}`;
  option3.innerHTML = `${question.answer3}`;
}

function loadNextQuestion() {
  const selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  //Check if there is a radio input checked
  if (!selectedOption) {
    alert("Please select your answer!");
    return;
  }
  //Get value of selected radio
  const answerScore = Number(
    selectedOption.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("data-total")
  );

  scoringData.push(selectedOption);
  ////Add the answer score to the score array
  score.push(answerScore);

  selectedAnswersData.push();

  function getMostFrequent(scoringData) {
    if (scoringData.length == 0) return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = scoringData[0],
      maxCount = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < scoringData.length; i++) {
      var el = score[i];
      if (modeMap[el] == null) modeMap[el] = 1;
      else modeMap[el]++;
      if (modeMap[el] > maxCount) {
        maxEl = el;
        maxCount = modeMap[el];
      }
    }
    return maxEl;
  }

  const finalScore = getMostFrequent();

  //Finally we incement the current question number ( to be used as the index for each array)
  currentQuestion++;

  //once finished clear checked
  selectedOption.checked = false;
  //If quiz is on the final question
  if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions - 1) {
    nextButton.textContent = "Finish";
  }
  //If the quiz is finished then we hide the questions container and show the results
  if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
    container.style.display = "none";
    result.innerHTML = `<h1 class="final-score">Your score: ${finalScore}</h1>
         <div class="summary">
            <h1>Summary</h1>
            <p>Possible - Personality Traits, see below for a summary based on your results:</p>
            <p>15 - 21- You Need Help</p>
            <p>10 - 15 - Good Soul</p>
            <p>5 - 10 - Meh </p>
            <p>5 - Are You Even Real</p>
        </div>
        <button class="restart">Restart Quiz</button>
         `;
    return;
  }
  generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
}

//Function to load previous question
function loadPreviousQuestion() {
  //Decrement quentions index
  currentQuestion--;
  //remove last array value;
  score.pop();
  //Generate the question
  generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
}

//Fuction to reset and restart the quiz;
function restartQuiz(e) {
  if (e.target.matches("button")) {
    //reset array index and score
    currentQuestion = 0;
    score = [];
    //Reload quiz to the start
    location.reload();
  }
}

generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
nextButton.addEventListener("click", loadNextQuestion);
previousButton.addEventListener("click", loadPreviousQuestion);
result.addEventListener("click", restartQuiz);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
  background: #000;
}
.quiz-container {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  padding: 3rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #00000010;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #f90;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.question {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.option {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f90;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.option:hover {
  background: #B36B00;
}
.option input:checked .option {
  background: #08038c;
  color: #000;
}
.controls > * {
  margin: 1rem;
}
button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
button.previous {
  background: #c84630;
}
button.next {
  background: #3c91e6;
}
button.restart {
  background: #0cf574;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
button.restart:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  transform: scale(1);
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.final-score {
  color: #f90;
}
.summary {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffffff50;
  color: #f90;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.summary h1 {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Personality Quiz</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="quiz-container">
        <div class="title">Personality Quiz</div>
        <div id="question" class="question"></div>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" />
            <span class="option1"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" />
            <span class="option2"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="3" />
            <span class="option3"></span>
        </label>
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="previous">Previous</button>
            <button class="next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="result">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just providing the relevant code would be enough, its really hard to tell what's going on and pinpoint the part that causes the error with all this unwanted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add scoringData to  const finalScore = getMostFrequent();

```js
// QUESTIONS

const questions = [
  {
    question: "Question 1",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 2",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 3",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 4",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 5",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 6",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 7",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 8",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 9",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  },
  {
    question: "Question 10",
    answer1: "choice 1",
    answer1Total: "1",
    answer2: "choice 2",
    answer2Total: "2",
    answer3: "choice 3",
    answer3Total: "3"
  }
];

let currentQuestion = 0;
let score = [];
let selectedAnswersData = [];
let scoringData = [];
const totalQuestions = questions.length;

const container = document.querySelector(".quiz-container");
const questionEl = document.querySelector(".question");
const option1 = document.querySelector(".option1");
const option2 = document.querySelector(".option2");
const option3 = document.querySelector(".option3");
const nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");
const previousButton = document.querySelector(".previous");
const restartButton = document.querySelector(".restart");
const result = document.querySelector(".result");

//Function to generate question
function generateQuestions(index) {
  //Select each question by passing it a particular index
  const question = questions[index];
  const option1Total = questions[index].answer1Total;
  const option2Total = questions[index].answer2Total;
  const option3Total = questions[index].answer3Total;
  //Populate html elements
  questionEl.innerHTML = `${index + 1}. ${question.question}`;
  option1.setAttribute("data-total", `${option1Total}`);
  option2.setAttribute("data-total", `${option2Total}`);
  option3.setAttribute("data-total", `${option3Total}`);
  option1.innerHTML = `${question.answer1}`;
  option2.innerHTML = `${question.answer2}`;
  option3.innerHTML = `${question.answer3}`;
}

function loadNextQuestion() {
  const selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  //Check if there is a radio input checked
  if (!selectedOption) {
    alert("Please select your answer!");
    return;
  }
  //Get value of selected radio
  const answerScore = Number(
    selectedOption.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("data-total")
  );

  scoringData.push(selectedOption);
  ////Add the answer score to the score array
  score.push(answerScore);

  selectedAnswersData.push();

  function getMostFrequent(scoringData) {
    if (scoringData.length == 0) return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = scoringData[0],
      maxCount = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < scoringData.length; i++) {
      var el = score[i];
      if (modeMap[el] == null) modeMap[el] = 1;
      else modeMap[el]++;
      if (modeMap[el] > maxCount) {
        maxEl = el;
        maxCount = modeMap[el];
      }
    }
    return maxEl;
  }

  const finalScore = getMostFrequent(scoringData);

  //Finally we incement the current question number ( to be used as the index for each array)
  currentQuestion++;

  //once finished clear checked
  selectedOption.checked = false;
  //If quiz is on the final question
  if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions - 1) {
    nextButton.textContent = "Finish";
  }
  //If the quiz is finished then we hide the questions container and show the results
  if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
    container.style.display = "none";
    result.innerHTML = `<h1 class="final-score">Your score: ${finalScore}</h1>
         <div class="summary">
            <h1>Summary</h1>
            <p>Possible - Personality Traits, see below for a summary based on your results:</p>
            <p>15 - 21- You Need Help</p>
            <p>10 - 15 - Good Soul</p>
            <p>5 - 10 - Meh </p>
            <p>5 - Are You Even Real</p>
        </div>
        <button class="restart">Restart Quiz</button>
         `;
    return;
  }
  generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
}

//Function to load previous question
function loadPreviousQuestion() {
  //Decrement quentions index
  currentQuestion--;
  //remove last array value;
  score.pop();
  //Generate the question
  generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
}

//Fuction to reset and restart the quiz;
function restartQuiz(e) {
  if (e.target.matches("button")) {
    //reset array index and score
    currentQuestion = 0;
    score = [];
    //Reload quiz to the start
    location.reload();
  }
}

generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
nextButton.addEventListener("click", loadNextQuestion);
previousButton.addEventListener("click", loadPreviousQuestion);
result.addEventListener("click", restartQuiz);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
  background: #000;
}
.quiz-container {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  padding: 3rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #00000010;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #f90;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.question {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.option {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f90;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.option:hover {
  background: #B36B00;
}
.option input:checked .option {
  background: #08038c;
  color: #000;
}
.controls > * {
  margin: 1rem;
}
button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
button.previous {
  background: #c84630;
}
button.next {
  background: #3c91e6;
}
button.restart {
  background: #0cf574;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
button.restart:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  transform: scale(1);
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.final-score {
  color: #f90;
}
.summary {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffffff50;
  color: #f90;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.summary h1 {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Personality Quiz</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="quiz-container">
        <div class="title">Personality Quiz</div>
        <div id="question" class="question"></div>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" />
            <span class="option1"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" />
            <span class="option2"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="3" />
            <span class="option3"></span>
        </label>
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="previous">Previous</button>
            <button class="next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="result">

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a function but not passing the argument to it in this line

```
 const finalScore = getMostFrequent();
```

change to

```
 const finalScore = getMostFrequent(scoringData);
```